Codeword length of a character with frequency more than 2/5 in huffman coding
Claim: Prove or disprove: If a text of length n contains a character with frequency >=2n\5 ,then there exists a codeword of length 1 in the Huffman tree.
My Thought: I know there’s a single character  with frequency >=2n\5 , so the rest of the frequencies sum to  <=3n\5
​
Let’s assume:
 the rest of the frequencies, splits into:
=2\5 (depth >= 1),
=\5
If Huffman merges  and C first, creating a node, and only later merges 
with this node,  ends up with a codeword longer than 1.
I saw  in the fourm already the proof, but I don't understand why my counter example is not valid.

(Do you use backslashes to denote division?) For an effective linebreak append two blanks to the preceding line.

"more than" or ">="? Which one is it?

Where did you see the proof?

Your counterexample is not valid because in your counterexample, the codeword for B has length 1, so there exists a codeword of length 1.
